# Year by year comparison of observed and simulated data using facet_wrap functionality of R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following `data.frame`

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 Sim = runif(1826,1,5), Obs = runif(1826,3,7)) %>% 
  separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month","Day")) %>% 
  mutate(Sim_Vol = Sim*86400, Obs_Vol = Obs*86400 ) %>% 
  filter(between(Month, 3,5))
```

I would like to first find the `total sum` of the `Sim_Vol` and `Obs_Vol` for each `Year` and then `bar plot` the `Yearly total data` using the `facet_wrap` functionality of `ggplot` for year by year comparison.
Attaching an example plot for further clearification

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
DF %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Sim_Vol, Obs_Vol), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("Vol")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name)) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

[image]